# Combining RGB and grayscale colors

Tags: php, css, colors, gradient, grayscale

I'm looking for a way to combine a RGB color with a grayscale color.

I am looking into this for a gradient generator that uses stored colors and a template (pre-made style properties for most venders) to create a CSS3 gradient.
I am sure their is a simple solution, but I can not seem to find it. I am not looking for anyone to make me a custom function, I just need to know how to make the function.

Comment: You would compare them the same way you compare any other rgb. In pseudo-code: `new rgb( (COLOR_R+GRAY_R)/2, (COLOR_G+GRAY_G)/2, (COLOR_B+GRAY_B)/2 )`

Comment: When you say combine, what do you mean? Average a grayscale and a color? Take the hue of a color with the luminosity of a grayscale? If you don't know how to describe it, use an example of what you want.

Comment: By combine, I mean take the hue of a color and combine it with the luminosity of a grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general approach will probably consist of three parts:

1. Convert the RGB color to HSL.
2. Keep the hue and saturation, but apply the luminosity of the desired greyscale color.
3. Convert this HSL triple back to RGB.

Wikipedia has [a great page on the HSL colorspace, including conversion formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space).  This information was used to create some JavaScript conversion functions by [Michael Jackson](http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript) *(yes, I'm serious)*:

### `rgbToHsl(r,g,b)`

```js
/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   Number  r       The red color value
 * @param   Number  g       The green color value
 * @param   Number  b       The blue color value
 * @return  Array           The HSL representation
 */
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}
```

### `hslToRgb(h,s,l)`

```js
/**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  l       The lightness
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

Since you said you're not looking for anyone to make you a custom function, I trust you'll find little trouble adapting these functions to PHP and leveraging them for your needs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the RGB channels with the brightness of the greyscale colour.

In javascript:

```
var grey = {r:123,g:123,b:123};
var color = {r:216,g:205,b:120};

var clamp = function(a,b,x){return Math.min(Math.max(a,x),b);}
var mixed = {
    r:clamp(0,255,color.r-(255-grey.r)),
    g:clamp(0,255,color.g-(255-grey.g)),
    b:clamp(0,255,color.b-(255-grey.b))
};// the final combined color.
```

Hope this can help you.